# Can Rabbits really only drop Rabbit's Foot when killed by the player in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft's Gamepedia [entry on rabbits foot](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rabbit%27s_Foot) says this:

> Each rabbit has a 10% chance to drop a rabbit's foot when killed by the player

And I've seen a bunch of videos on rabbit farms claiming the same, but I've just finished making one such rabbit farm, I bred a bunch of rabbits until the entity cramming limit was reached and some of them started dying off, so I pulled a lever which would drop the baby rabbits into a drainage system that would separate them from the big ones so more wouldn't die off, and after this I take a look at my loot chest, apparently a whole 15 rabbits died (cus 15 rabbit hide), but what's curious to me is that I also got 3 Rabbit's feet.

This doesn't line up with what the gamepedia entry says unless I missed something and entity cramming deaths count as player kills. Has the requirement for rabbits to be killed by players for their feet to drop been reverted? Or was this just some weird quirk?

Comment: Did you hit any of the rabbits (even if your hit didn't kill them)?

Comment: Nope, I never pressed LMB throughout this (Unless it was to break a block  outside of melee range of the rabbits, I can only hit the rabbits when they're bobbing up and down in the water, and I had the water off whenever I wasn't feeding them due to the lag it happens to induce)

Comment: I just realized that I'm in a unique position to test this out since I already have a farm built, I can just overpopulate it and see what happens. I tried using a crusher to kill them and I didn't get any feet, but I believe maybe the entity cramming death counts as a player kill, that would be pretty cool. Otherwise it would have to have been some kind of quirk.

Comment: I'm unable to produce it with entity cramming. Could there have been feet in the chest left over from a time you did kill them yourself?

Comment: Must have been something like that because I tried the same thing both creative and survival and couldn't replicate this. Must have been some weird quirk or an oversight, I'll answer with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to replicate the rabbit foot drops by crushing them and by cramming again and I didn't seem to be able to replicate these results, therefore it must have been either a quirk due to lag, or I must have already had feet in my chest that I didn't remember.

So in summary, rabbits still need to be killed by the player to drop rabbit's foot.